# Clean up . delete all the docker images except the one in use

Tags: docker

I know there are some prune commands but they do not delete the normal images hanging out there , I need a way to auto delete all the images except the one currently in use by the container.

Maybe I will need to write my script that finds all the images that are not in use and then delete them. Is there any built in docker command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is such command

`docker system prune --all`

```
 -a, --all         Remove all unused images not just dangling ones
```

Comment: thank you. although it doesnt really answer my need, but it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

docker images | grep -v KEEPTHIS | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs docker rmi -f